# Accessing an element inside another element JavaScript data

Tags: javascript, json

let's say I have this piece of data:

```
{
"welcome": "This is Json data that helps see what happened around the world so far",
"2020": [
    [{
        "Title": "The Duke and Duchess of Sussex shocked both sides of the pond on Jan. 8 when they announced they were stepping down as “senior” royals.",
        "Description": "Prince Harry and Meghan Markle quit royal family",
        "Date": "Jan",
        "Photo": "https://nypost.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2020/08/queen-meghan-markle-prine-harry.jpg?quality=90&strip=all&w=1236",
        "Country": "Uk",

        "Title2": "COVID-19 pandemic",
        "Description2": "The World Health Organization announced Jan. 9 that a deadly coronavirus had emerged in Wuhan, China. In a matter of months, the virus has spread across the globe to more than 20 million people, resulting in at least 751,000 deaths.",
        "Date2": "Jan",
        "Country2": "world wide"

    }]
]
}
```

How do I access `[2020][2nd title]`?
I did something like this but it didn't work:

```
data.2020[5]
```

Comment: `data[2020][1].Title` ?

Comment: Didn't work too :( @OwenKelvin

Comment: Your `json` object is invalid, please provide a valid `JSON` data

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: I've updated it, Sorry for that! @OwenKelvin

Comment: I want `Title2` (COVID-19 pandemic) @LahiruTennakoon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply break the problem step by step

```js
const data = {
"welcome": "This is Json data that helps see what happened around the world so far",
"2020": [
[{
    "Title": "The Duke and Duchess of Sussex shocked both sides of the pond on Jan. 8 when they announced they were stepping down as “senior” royals.",
    "Description": "Prince Harry and Meghan Markle quit royal family",
    "Date": "Jan",
    "Photo": "https://nypost.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2020/08/queen-meghan-markle-prine-harry.jpg?quality=90&strip=all&w=1236",
    "Country": "Uk",

    "Title2": "COVID-19 pandemic",
    "Description2": "The World Health Organization announced Jan. 9 that a deadly coronavirus had emerged in Wuhan, China. In a matter of months, the virus has spread across the globe to more than 20 million people, resulting in at least 751,000 deaths.",
    "Date2": "Jan",
    "Country2": "world wide"

}]
]
}

console.log(data[2020][0][0].Title2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could access the properties using bracket notation as shown below.

```js
const data = {
  "welcome": "This is Json data that helps see what happened around the world so far",
  "2020": [
    [{
      "Title": "The Duke and Duchess of Sussex shocked both sides of the pond on Jan. 8 when they announced they were stepping down as “senior” royals.",
      "Description": "Prince Harry and Meghan Markle quit royal family",
      "Date": "Jan",
      "Photo": "https://nypost.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2020/08/queen-meghan-markle-prine-harry.jpg?quality=90&strip=all&w=1236",
      "Country": "Uk",

      "Title2": "COVID-19 pandemic",
      "Description2": "The World Health Organization announced Jan. 9 that a deadly coronavirus had emerged in Wuhan, China. In a matter of months, the virus has spread across the globe to more than 20 million people, resulting in at least 751,000 deaths.",
      "Date2": "Jan",
      "Country2": "world wide"

    }]
  ]
};

console.log(data[2020][0][0]['Title2']);
```